# Updating progress bar using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I am not getting how can I update progress bar. 
Here is my code,

```
socket.on('value',function(data){
    console.log(data); // For example, this prints value '10'
 // Here i have to update progress bar.
}
```

I want to divide value by 10, equally and adjust the progress width to 100%.
Can anyone help me doing this? Is it possible? I am new to this concept. Please help me solving this.

Comment: Let me clarify: you have a <progress> element (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress), and you need to update it inside your callback? It's not clear from the question

Comment: This question is unclear. Would you please add more context, and some more examples of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `<progress>` element, you can update it inside your callback like that:

```
// suppose your <progress> element is defined this way:
<progress min=0 max=100 id="myProgressBar"></progress>

// updating it:
socket.on('value',function(data){
    console.log(data); // For example, this prints value '10'
    $("#myProgressBar").val(data / 10) // here is the one way to update it
}
```

Also you can omit dividing by 10 (and just call `$("#myProgressBar").val(data)` ) and just specify `max=10` (or whatever your maximum value is) inside your element's attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much